# how do i create decision variables

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, solver, mixed-integer-programming

how can i create decision variable of type xp.sos(fico xpress solver) from a list like this 
`i have 2 lists K and D with these set of elements as seen below.K is a list of trips and J is a list of machines

K= ['D-1-D', 'D-2-D', 'D-3-D', 'D-4-D', 'D-4-2-1-D', 'D-2-1-D', 'D-4-1-D', 'D-2-4-3-D'].
J= ["A","B"]

```
with  decision variables 

1) Y_{kj} is 0 or 1, equal to 1 if trip k is executed by UAV j

2)Z_{k1k2}^j is 0 or 1, equal to 1 if trip k1 and trip k2 are executed in sequence by UAV j and 0 otherwise
```

Comment: Conceptually, I don't think this is a proper use of a SOS variable. SOS 2 variables are for interpolation.  Are you sure you know what you are doing here?

Comment: honestly i used sos because i thought it would tackle the issue of sequence. is there a much proper way to go around it if i may ask?Do i have to still declare it as an xp.var??

Comment: Yes, see: https://examples.xpress.fico.com/example.pl?id=Indicators_python. A SOS set is not a variable. Note that SOS2 is for 2 adjacent nonzeros. It is meant for interpolation, not for what you want. I suggest to go back to basics and first develop a proper mathematical model.